# Get element from list that contains another list

Tags: java, stream

I have this configuration with java:

```
Student {
   private List<Note> notes;
}

Note {
   private int value;

   // Constructor - getters - setters
}

School {
   Private List<Student> students;

// Constructor - getters - setters
}
```

I want the following behavior:

Students :

```
S1 : note1(value=10), note2(value=16)

S2 : note1(value=7), note2(value=18), note3(value=2)

S3 : note1(value=19)
```

I want to manage an object with a list of schools as:

```
Manage {
   private List<School> schools;
}
```

And I want to get the school who has the student with the higher note.

In this example: the result would be S3 because we have one student with the higher note 19.

How can I achieve this behavior using Java Stream?

Comment: Where do you get the school name?

Comment: I want just get school from the list of the school by filtering it using Student object and notes.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to use comparison between objects and other ways but I can't get it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Stream<Map.Entry<School,Student>>` of all the pairs of `School`s and `Student`s, and then find the entry having the `Student` with the max value.

For that purpose I suggest adding to `Student` class a `getMaxValue()` method that would return the max value of all the `Student`s `Note`s.

```
Optional<School> school =
    schools.stream()
           .flatMap(sc -> sc.getStudents()
                            .stream()
                            .map(st -> new SimpleEntry<>(sc,st)))
           .collect(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getValue().getMaxValue())))
           .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
```

Comment: Finally I got it by using Map. Thanks you very much !